# Hibernate: Referencing a table inside an entity with hql

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am working on a project for a class hibernating a database from mysql to microsoft sql server 2008 and then using hibernate to access the microsoft sql database. I am trying to access the table named "teamseasonplayer" in my database. The teamseasonplayer table is created under the entity teamSeason in the teamSeason class as shown

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name = "teamseason")
public class TeamSeason implements Serializable{

@EmbeddedId
TeamSeasonId id;

@Embeddable
static class TeamSeasonId implements Serializable { 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "teamid", referencedColumnName = "teamid", insertabl = false, updatable = false)
    Team team;
    @Column(name = "year")
    Integer teamYear;   
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof TeamSeasonId)){
            return false;
        }
        TeamSeasonId other = (TeamSeasonId)obj;
        return (this.team == other.team &&
                this.teamYear == other.teamYear);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        Integer hash = 0;
        if(this.team != null) hash += this.team.hashCode();
        if(this.teamYear != null) hash += this.teamYear.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "teamseasonplayer", 
   joinColumns={

     @JoinColumn(name="teamId", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
     @JoinColumn(name="year",  insertable = false, updatable = false)}, 

   inverseJoinColumns={

     @JoinColumn(name="playerId", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();

@Column
Integer gamesPlayed;
@Column
Integer wins;
@Column
Integer losses;
@Column
Integer rank;
@Column
Integer totalAttendance;
```

In my HibernateUtil class I am writing a method to retrieve playerId based on year and teamId from the teamseasonplayer table my function looks like this

```
public static List<Object> retrieveTS(Integer teamQuery, Integer yearQuery){
    //List<TeamSeason> list = null;
    List<Object> list2 = null;
    int playerId = 1111;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
    try{
        tx.begin();

        String hql = "select teamId from teamseasonplayer where teamId = :teamId and year = :teamYear";
        org.hibernate.Query query;
        query = session.createQuery(hql);

    query.setParameter("teamId", teamQuery);    
    query.setParameter("teamYear", yearQuery);

    list2 = query.list();
    tx.commit();
    }catch (Exception e){
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }
    return list2;
}
```

my hql statement however is returning an error. Given the way I have my teamSeason class constructed how would I reference the teamseasonplayer table with an hql statement. The console output exception I get is beneath

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: teamseasonplayer is not mapped [select teamId from teamseasonplayer where teamId = :teamId and year = :teamYear]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:96)
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at dataaccesslayer.HibernateUtil.retrieveTS(HibernateUtil.java:131)
at controller.TeamController.processRoster(TeamController.java:78)
at controller.TeamController.performAction(TeamController.java:35)
at controller.BaseController.process(BaseController.java:30)
at controller.TeamController.init(TeamController.java:21)
at webserver.WebRequestHandler.generateBytesToSend(WebRequestHandler.java:56)
at webserver.WebRequestHandler.processRequest(WebRequestHandler.java:35)
at webserver.WebRequestHandler.run(WebRequestHandler.java:22)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help or suggestions would be amazing I've been stuck on this for a while.

EDIT: team.java

```
@Entity(name = "team")
public class Team {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer teamId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id.team")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
Set<TeamSeason> seasons = new HashSet<TeamSeason>();

@Column
String name;
@Column
String league;
@Column
Integer yearFounded;
@Column 
Integer yearLast;
```

Comment: suppose you modify the select query as `select teamId from TeamSeason where team.id= :teamId and teamYear= :teamYear`

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'teamId' {originalText=teamId}

Comment: can you share the `Team.java`. suppose the teamId is not present in the `Team.java` file. Mean time Suppose you to look this [post](http://www.journaldev.com/2954/hibernate-query-language-hql-example-tutorial) using `HQL` to get a understating of the issue.

Comment: Select Query should be `select team.teamId from TeamSeason where team.teamId= :teamId and teamYear= :teamYear`. Hope this helps.